# Pricing Model for desktop computers

Tags: probability, bayesian, modeling, posterior

I am trying to implement a pricing model to automatic price desktops based on some attributes(say memory, disk and brand for now).

I have collected some sold history data from the internet and they are more like in a "[melted](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper)" format.

Say, there are three transactions have been done in the history.

```
TransactionID    Brand    Memory    Disk    SoldPrice
1                Lenovo   1G        60G     $100
2                IBM      NA        60G     $150
3                Lenovo   4G        NA      $200
...
```

And the data in I have looks like this:

```
SoldPrice    Attribute    Value
$100         Brand        Lenovo
$100         Memory       1G
$100         Disk         60G
$150         Brand        IBM
$150         Disk         60G
$200         Brand        Lenovo
$200         Memory       4G
```

I know I can use reshape(2) package in R to cast the data back to the wide format which might be a perfect machine learning problem using whatever methods(Linear regression, or omnipotent random forest).

However, my gut feeling tells me will it actually be a perfect fit for Bayesian algorithm if I don't change anything? So you can easily get the probability distribution for each conditions. So it will be easier to calculate.

```
P(Price|Brand*Memory*Disk) = P(Price|Brand) * P(Price|Memory) * P(Price|Disk)
```

Then we can have a plot of the probability for different prices vs the given computer spec.

will be very easy to calculate and actually will have a better accuracy than other models?

I am more on the programming side so please provide more detail if you are mentioning graduate level math. I wish I can get some mathematical suggestion or guidance about my thought here instead of Stackoverflow.

Comment: The data you have appears to have lost critical information. For instance, suppose your three transactions were all at the same price.  Then your data file would tell you that two brands (Lenovo, IBM) were involved, two disks of the same size (60 GB) were involved, and RAM of 1GB and 4GB were involved. You can't even tell there were three transactions, much less which combinations of brand, disk, and RAM were sold!

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the confusion. There is actually a column "sold time-stamp" that I did not listed here for POC, which could be used to identify if the records belong to one transaction. I am super curious what is the matter if we can not trace back the transaction. We can get the prob distribution for each separate variable. And we can then take them as independent variables to calculate the product based on each one.

Comment: As you saw in my simple example, without that transaction ID you don't even know how many transactions occurred and you have insufficient information about the missing values, so you wouldn't have a prayer of estimating the contribution of each type of component to the cost, much less obtaining an error estimate. Your second data structure does not distinguish between *absence* of a component and *missing information* about it. Shall we presume that "NA" in your first data structure therefore means absence of a component and not lack of data?

Comment: @whuber The NAs in the data set means the seller did not put down the specs for that drop downlist, maybe he doesn't know, maybe he forgot to fill in. For example, my dad has a desktop that he only knows it has a 16GB memory without knowing anything else. And he tries to sell that on eBay only listing a desktop with 16GB memory which has a very big probably that that desktop will come with big disk and fast CPU just because 16GB always comes as expensive based on all the records we have related with memory attributes.

Comment: Then your second format is useless for your purpose, because it does not make that critical distinction between "absent" and "missing." At a minimum it needs to include records corresponding to the "NA" values in the first format. You have an [imputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=imputation) problem to deal with, regardless of the format.

Comment: @whuber Absent you mean, someone post a desktop that doesn't have memory / disk ?

Comment: Sure. (Plenty of systems are sold without various components such as disks, graphics cards, optical readers, etc.) Even worse, there could be (and likely is) an association between information being missing and the attributes of the missing components. For instance, it is plausible that people would be more aware of--and more likely to list the values of--more recent, high-end, or attractive components. If you don't handle this possibility appropriately in your analysis you can wind up with biased (perhaps grievously wrong) results.

Comment: @whuber Really Really appreciate the patient explanation about the value of missing values.. That is indeed a good tip. I will saw some values with NA and None and ! which I don't understand. Seems like your concern totally makes sense.